# Dimension reduction Using PCA while preserving variance in percentage

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

i am  trying to reduce the dimensions of MNIST dataset using PCA. Trick is, i have to preserve the certain percentage of variance(say 80%) while reducing the dimension. I am using Scikit learn. I am doing pca.get_variance *ratio* but it gives me same values with different dot location like 9.7 or .97 or .097. i am also tried pca.get_variance() but i assume that's not the answer. My question is how to ensure that i have reduce the dimension with certain variance percentage preserve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply PCA without passing the `n_components` argument, then the `explained_variance_ratio_` attribute of the PCA object will give you the information you need. This attribute indicates the fraction of total variance associated with the corresponding eigenvector. Here is an example copied directly from the current stable [PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) documentation:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
>>> X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
>>> pca = PCA(n_components=2)
>>> pca.fit(X)
PCA(copy=True, n_components=2, whiten=False)
>>> print(pca.explained_variance_ratio_) 
[ 0.99244...  0.00755...]
```

In your case, if you apply `np.cumsum` to the `explained_variance_ratio_` attribute, then the number of principal components you need to keep corresponds to the position of the first element in `np.cumsum(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)` that is greater than or equal to 0.8.

Comment: this make things a bit clear ...but what do i have to do to preserve the variance according to the certain percentage given as a parameter like preserve 50%, 60% etc?  i guess its something to do with tuning the n_component in PCA.

Comment: You could run LDA without specifying `n_components` to figure out how many you need to retain, then re-run LDA using the number of components required to achieve your desired level of variance. Alternately, you could do the transformation yourself by subtracting the mean from your data and matrix-multiplying with the subset of eigenvectors produced by LDA. The latter is more efficient but requires more code.